# Regex get everything including brackets

Tags: php, regex

I've got this script to rename my files

I want it to get everything after the / and before the .rar

```
 /var/www/html/raw/File Name (J)(ProjectG).rar
```

This is the code i currently have:

```
preg_match("#/var/www/html/raw/(.*?).rar#i", $output,  $matches);
```

But it's only returning the stuff that isn't inside brackets, How can i get everything.

```
Array ( [0] => /var/www/html/raw/File Name [1] => File Name )
```

Thanks

Comment: check your input string for preg_match, your regex [works for me](http://www.switchplane.com/awesome/preg-match-regular-expression-tester?pattern=%23%2Fvar%2Fwww%2Fhtml%2Fraw%2F%28.*%3F%29.rar%23&subject=%2Fvar%2Fwww%2Fhtml%2Fraw%2FFile+Name+%28J%29%28ProjectG%29.rar)

Comment: @yate This is like what i'm getting: [link](http://www.switchplane.com/awesome/preg-match-regular-expression-tester?pattern=%23%2Fvar%2Fwww%2Fhtml%2Fraw%2F%28.*%3F%29.nds%23&subject=%2Fvar%2Fwww%2Fhtml%2Fraw%2F0075+-+Nintendogs+-+Miniature+Dachshund+and+Friends+%28J%29%28Trashman%29.nds).

Comment: you need to [escape your period](http://www.switchplane.com/awesome/preg-match-regular-expression-tester?pattern=%23%2Fvar%2Fwww%2Fhtml%2Fraw%2F%28.*%3F%29%5C.nds%23&subject=%2Fvar%2Fwww%2Fhtml%2Fraw%2F0075+-+Nintendogs+-+Miniature+Dachshund+and+Friends+%28J%29%28Trashman%29.nds) in `\.nds`.  its ending that match at frieNDS because your matching any character followed by nds.

Comment: Oh wow, thank you! If you make an answer yate i will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escape the period in the extension.

```
"#/var/www/html/raw/(.*?)\.rar#i"
```

Without the backslash you will match any character followed by `rar`, which will may or may not cut off the match early depending on the file name. [In this example](http://www.switchplane.com/awesome/preg-match-regular-expression-tester?pattern=%23%2Fvar%2Fwww%2Fhtml%2Fraw%2F%28.%2A%3F%29.nds%23&subject=%2Fvar%2Fwww%2Fhtml%2Fraw%2F0075+-+Nintendogs+-+Miniature+Dachshund+and+Friends+%28J%29%28Trashman%29.nds) it will end at the `ends` in `Friends`.

Answer (score 1):

This is easy, you don't need regex for this. Try doing it like this:

```
$file_path = '/var/www/html/raw/File Name (J)(ProjectG).rar';

$file_name = end(explode('/', $file_path));

var_dump($file_name);
```

Alternatively, you can use the PHP built-in function [basename()](http://php.net/basename) for this also:

```
var_dump(basename('/var/www/html/raw/File Name (J)(ProjectG).rar'));
```

both method outputs:

[image]

---

If you want to get rid of the `.rar` after the file name is worked out, use a `str_replace` on it, for example:

```
$file_name = str_replace(
    '.rar',
    '',
    basename('/var/www/html/raw/File Name (J)(ProjectG).rar'));
```

Comment: The only issue is that bit of text that its looking in has lots of other text within it, Will it still work ?

Comment: can you give an example?

Comment: @LatheesanKanes Im extracting files using unrar then it displays results like this: 
Extracting from /var/www/html/0001-1000/0069.rar

Extracting  /var/www/html/raw/File Name (J)(ProjectG).ext       0%  1%  2%  3%  4%  5%  6%

Comment: Are you extracting the file in PHP? if so, can you show the you code?

Comment: Yeah i am extracting using PHP, im just trying to find out the filename once its been extracted. The regex im using works about 90% of the time but theres been a couple files that it wont display the whole name. I'm using $command = "unrar x -y /var/www/html/0001-1000/$r_number.rar /var/www/html/raw/";      $output = shell_exec($command);

Comment: can you write the raw `$output` to a file and post it here -> http://www.pastebin.com (i'd like to see how the output looks like, with all the spacing / line feeds etc...).

Comment: http://pastebin.com/a2zPyeSY , you can see its only getting half of the file name for some reason, i don't understand why.

Comment: Yate has figured it out. thanks for your help anyway, i learnt something from you answer!

Comment: Yea... after seeing the raw output, figured you'll need to use regex.

Answer (score 0):

**Don't use a regex.**  Regexes are not a magic wand that you wave at every problem that happens to involve strings.

You don't want "everything after the last /".  You want the filename.  There are already functions built in to PHP to extract filenames from paths.  In this case, you want `basename`.

```
$path = '/var/www/html/raw/File Name (J)(ProjectG).rar';
print basename( $path );
```